# Conan.io during compile step or already on checkout

Tags: c++, conan

I am evaluating [conan.io](https://www.conan.io/) for my C++ project. Am I understanding correctly that conan dependencies are executed/resolved as part of the the build system?

The [documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/introduction.html) states:

> Also Conan works with any build system. In the documentation, CMake
>   will be widely used, because it is portable and well known. But Conan
>   does not depend on CMake at all; it is not a requirement. Conan is
>   totally orthogonal to the build system.

I am wondering why it's not on source control level. Don't you want a copy of your binaries already on checkout? I don't understand why this is not invoked by git or Perforce

Comment: You can totally do that if you want:
https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout . Personally, I'm used to pulling dependencies as part of the build (`npm install`, `dotnet restore`, `mvn dependency:resolve`, etc)

Comment: Thanks! I would accept that as an answer. I am just wondering why thats not the "hello world example"

Comment: I think that binaries are not copied at checkout because there are different binaries for different build configurations, e.g. you can build `Debug` or `Release` modes, you can use different compilers and so on. All these parameters are defined with build system and not known on checkout

Comment: That makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think that binaries are not copied at checkout because there are different binaries for different build configurations, e.g. you can build `Debug` or `Release` modes, you can use different compilers and so on. All these parameters are defined with build system and not known on checkout